# Next.js router: how to make page refresh on url change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have page where a user can narrow their search using filters. The issue is that when a user clicks on a filter to filter properties by "rent" or "buy", the url does not refresh to reflect the changes. The changes do however appear in the URL, which is what I want, but I have to manually press enter to refresh the page with the specified filters, so that changes would appear.

[image]

As you can see in the photo, the properties listed are not "for rent" properties, so the only way to correctly see the rental properties is to manually enter the url: `http://localhost:3000/search?purpose=for-rent&minPrice=20000`

```
import {
  Flex,
  Select,
  Box,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Image from "next/image";
import { filterData, getFilterValues } from "../utils/filterData";

class searchFilters extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filters: filterData,
    };
  }

  handleChange = (filterValues) => {
    const path = this.props.params.pathname;
    const { query } = this.props.params;
    const values = getFilterValues(filterValues);
    values.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.value && filterValues?.[item.name]) {
        query[item.name] = item.value;
      }
    });
    this.props.params.push({ pathname: path, query: query });
  };

  render() {
    const { filters } = this.state;
    return (
      <Flex bg="gray.100" p="4" justifyContent="center" flexWrap="wrap">
        {filters.map((filter) => (
          <Box key={filter.queryName}>
            <Select
              placeholder={filter.placeholder}
              w="fit-content"
              p="2"
              onChange={(e) =>
                this.handleChange({ [filter.queryName]: e.target.value })
              }
            >
              {filter.items.map((item) => (
                <option value={item.value} key={item.value}>
                  {item.name}
                </option>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </Box>
        ))}
      </Flex>
    );
  }
}

const withParams = (Component) => {
  return (props) => <Component {...props} params={useRouter()} />;
};

export default withParams(searchFilters);
```

Comment: Two things: 1) You don't need to create a `withParams` HOC to pass the router to your class component - Next.js provides the [`withRouter`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#withrouter) HOC for that; 2) You should update the `filters` state variable based on the query params changes to have the UI reflect the changes too.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the same component, it will not reload the page. You can detect the param change with `useEffect` hook and add the refreshig logic within it. This would reload the data as per the new param.

```
const { query } = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
  // Refresh logic
}, [query.purpose)]);
```